# How to get a simple test to run with rspec + fabrication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, fabrication-gem

I'm trying to get a simple test up and running with rspec + fabrication. Unfortunately, not too many decent articles on this.

In spec/model/event_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Event do
  subject { Fabricate(:event) }

  describe "#full_name" do
    its(:city) { should == "LA" }
  end

end
```

In spec/fabricators/event_fabricator.rb

```
Fabricator(:event) do
  user { Fabricate(:user) }

  # The test works if I uncomment this line:
  # user_id 1

  city "LA"
  description "Best event evar"
end
```

In spec/fabricators/user_fabricator.rb

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  name 'Foobar'
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
end
```

I keep getting:

```
 1) Event#full_name city 
     Failure/Error: subject { Fabricate(:event) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

**PS** if anyone knows of any online articles / tutorials worth a read on getting started with rspec and fabrication. Do let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the features of Fabricator is that it lazily generates associations, meaning that your `User` won't get generated unless the `user` accessor is called on the `Event` model.

It looks like your `Event` model has a validation which requires a `User` to be present. If this is the case, you need to declare your fabricator like this:

```
Fabricator(:event) do
  # This forces the association to be created
  user!
  city "LA"
  description "Best event evar"
end
```

This ensures that the `User` model is created along with the `Event`, which will allow your validations to pass.

see: http://fabricationgem.org/#!defining-fabricators

Comment: The lazy load has since been removed from Fabrication as per https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/issues/71. There is no need to add ! anymore.